# Break string into list of characters in Python

Tags: python, list, readlines

Essentially I want to suck a line of text from a file, assign the characters to a list, and create a list of all the separate characters in a list -- a list of lists.

At the moment, I've tried this:

```
fO = open(filename, 'rU')
fL = fO.readlines()
```

That's all I've got. I don't quite know how to extract the single characters and assign them to a new list.

The line I get from the file will be something like:

```
fL = 'FHFF HHXH XXXX HFHX'
```

I want to turn it into this list, with each single character on its own:

```
['F', 'H', 'F', 'F', 'H', ...]
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Strings are iterable (just like a list).

I'm interpreting that you really want something like:

```
fd = open(filename,'rU')
chars = []
for line in fd:
   for c in line:
       chars.append(c)
```

or

```
fd = open(filename, 'rU')
chars = []
for line in fd:
    chars.extend(line)
```

or

```
chars = []
with open(filename, 'rU') as fd:
    map(chars.extend, fd)
```

chars would contain all of the characters in the file.

Comment: @FlexedCookie [`itertools.chain`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) is really the simplest for this -- `chars = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(open(filename, 'rU)))`.

Comment: The code above does not account for the whitespaces, i.e., `" "`

Answer (score 166):

You can do this using [list](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#list):

```
new_list = list(fL)
```

Be aware that any spaces in the line will be included in this list, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: with utf-8 characters it doesn't work as expected. For string "zyć", i was expecting a list of 3 characters, instead i got this list: ['z', 'y', '\xc4', '\x87'].
Could you please guide on what could be done to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: i've got my answer, i forgot to add 'u' before my string, so it was not getting treated as unicode. thanks.

Answer (score 62):

I'm a bit late it seems to be, but...

```
a='hello'
print list(a)
# ['h','e','l','l', 'o']
```

Answer (score 20):

### python >= 3.5

Version 3.5 onwards allows the use of [PEP 448 - Extended Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
>>> string = 'hello'
>>> [*string]
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

This is a specification of the language syntax, so it is faster than calling `list`:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit("list('hello')")
0.3042821969866054
>>> timeit("[*'hello']")
0.1582647830073256
```

Answer (score 10):

So to add the string `hello` to a list as individual characters, try this:

```
newlist = []
newlist[:0] = 'hello'
print (newlist)

  ['h','e','l','l','o']
```

However, it is easier to do this:

```
splitlist = list(newlist)
print (splitlist)
```

Comment: But even easier is: `newlist = list('hello')`

Comment: @tim Yeah, just noticed I hadn't put that in :)

Answer (score 7):

```
fO = open(filename, 'rU')
lst = list(fO.read())
```

Answer (score 5):

Or use a fancy list comprehension, which are supposed to be "computationally more efficient", when working with very very large files/lists

```
fd = open(filename,'r')
chars = [c for line in fd for c in line if c is not " "]
fd.close()
```

Btw: The answer that was accepted does not account for the whitespaces...

Answer (score 4):

```
a='hello world'
map(lambda x:x, a)
```

> ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']

An easy way is using function “map()”.

Answer (score 3):

In python many things are iterable including files and strings.
Iterating over a filehandler gives you a list of all the lines in that file.
Iterating over a string gives you a list of all the characters in that string.

```
charsFromFile = []
filePath = r'path\to\your\file.txt' #the r before the string lets us use backslashes

for line in open(filePath):
    for char in line:
        charsFromFile.append(char) 
        #apply code on each character here
```

or if you want a one liner

```
#the [0] at the end is the line you want to grab.
#the [0] can be removed to grab all lines
[list(a) for a in list(open('test.py'))][0]
```

.

.

Edit: as agf mentions you can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`

His method is better, unless you want the ability to specify which lines to grab
`list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(open(filename, 'rU)))`

This does however require one to be familiar with itertools, and as a result looses some readablity

If you only want to iterate over the chars, and don't care about storing a list, then I would use the nested for loops. This method is also the most readable.

Answer (score 0):

Because strings are (immutable) sequences they can be unpacked similar to lists:

```
with open(filename, 'rU') as fd:
    multiLine = fd.read()
    *lst, = multiLine
```

When running map(lambda x: x, multiLine) this is clearly more efficient, but in fact it returns a map object instead of a list.

```
with open(filename, 'rU') as fd:
    multiLine = fd.read()
    list(map(lambda x: x, multiLine))
```

Turning the map object into a list will take longer than the unpacking method.