# Adding different items to the list from the string

Tags: python, list

Let's say, there is a string that can be:

- "3d6"
- "t3d6"
- "3h4d6"
- "t3h4d6"
- "6 t3d6"
- "6 t3h4d6+6" and similar possible variations.

Is there a way to run through the string and add the items from it to the list based on them being letters/numbers/symbols/other stuff? For example, `"6 t3h10d6+6"` would result in `[6, " ", "t", 3, "h", 10, "d", 6, "+", 6]` as the list.

I'm working on a telegram bot that uses the python to answer users' inputs with dice calculations results and the hardest part is processing the user input. Right now the input is being processed through the clumsy if statements complex. There might be a better way to process the user input and I would be glad to hear your advice!

Not a duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833392/break-string-into-list-of-characters-in-python). The question is about breaking a string into list of characters, basically turning a string into a list of strings. My question is about breaking string into list of different items that can be both strings and integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Break string into list of characters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833392/break-string-into-list-of-characters-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `regex` for that (by specifying to find all digit and non digit characters):

```
>>> x
'6 t3h4df6d+!643'
>>> __import__("re").findall('\d+|\s+|\D+', x)
['6', ' ', 't', '3', 'h', '4', 'df', '6', 'd+!', '643']
```

As you can see the above expression doesn't separate `d` from `+!`.
If that is a problem you can slightly modify the above regular
expression to:

```
>>> x = '6 t3h4df6d+!643'
>>> re.findall('\d+|\s+|[a-zA-Z]+|\D+', x)
['6', ' ', 't', '3', 'h', '4', 'df', '6', 'd', '+!', '643']
```

which separates them completely!

**Update**

If you want to split strings as single characters (e.g. `"xy"` as `['x','y']`) you can change the above `regex` expression to:

```
>>> x = '6 t3h4df6d+!643'
>>> __import__("re").findall('\d+|\s+|\w|\D+', x)
['6', ' ', 't', '3', 'h', '4', 'd', 'f', '6', 'd', '+!', '643']
```

Comment: very very pythonic

Comment: and you taught me a new stuff. I was not even aware of that... omg... the `__import__("re").findall(regex,variable)` OMG!!! wowwow

Comment: Wow, thanks! You seem to be the only person to notice that `"10"` should result in `[10]` and not in `[1, 0]`.

Comment: @AntonyPetrushko Glad to help!

Comment: `__import__("re").findall(regex,variable)` I like that !

Comment: This doesn't answer your question. This is what is written in the question description: For example, "6 t3h10d6+6" would result in [6, " ", "t", 3, "h", 10, "d", 6, "+", 6] as the list.

Comment: `re.findall('\d+|\s+|\D+', "6 t3h10d6+1")` returns `['6', ' ', 't', '3', 'h', '10', 'd', '6', '+', '1']`. The items inside of the list are all of the string type but, though not mentioned in the question, it is not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you are comfortable using list comprehensions [List comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
  [ int(c) if c.isdigit() else c for c in "6 t3h4d6+6" ]
```

Output

```
[6, ' ', 't', 3, 'h', 4, 'd', 6, '+', 6]
```

Comment: Note that this wouldn't extract `10` from `"6 t3h10d6+6"`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) and list comprehensions to achieve the desired result :

```
from itertools import groupby
text = "6 t3h10d6+6"
substrings = groupby(text, lambda c: (c.isdigit(), c.isspace()))
print([int(''.join(l)) if d else ''.join(l) for (d, s), l in substrings])
# => [6, ' ', 't', 3, 'h', 10, 'd', 6, '+', 6]
```

Note that `'10'` is parsed as `10`, not `'10'` or `[1, 0]`.

Comment: And I also can note that `" t"` is parsed as `" t"` and not as `[" ", "t"]`. Close enough!

Comment: @AntonyPetrushko: Indeed. How should `"ab"` be parsed?

Comment: Good observation! Sorry not to give a best example in the question. `"ab"` should be parsed as `["a", "b"]` and `" b"` as `[" ", "b"]`. Basically it should turn a string into a list of numbers (NOT digits) and single character.