# How can I convert single word string to a list?

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

I am working on some code in python, here I want to work on different indexes of a single word. For example, I took input from user in a string. If user enters "Banana" than I cant modify any index of this word say 2nd or 3rd index as it is a string. So my question is how can I convert this string to a list so that I can access and edit each letter of this word? Or is there any method that I take input in list with each letter on each index not complete word on first index?

I have tried str.split() but it just removes spaces between the word whereas I am dealing with a single-word string so split do not works with it

Comment: You ask "So my question is how can I convert this string to a list so that I can access and edit each letter of this word?" Did you happen to search "Python string to list" in Google yet?

Comment: python has a `list` built-in to convert many things into lists. read the doc: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list

Comment: @dfundako: That Google search is insufficient.  It needs to be "Python string to list of characters, which yields [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833392/break-string-into-list-of-characters-in-python).

Comment: One thing you can do is convert the string to a `bytearray`. This will allow you to access and modify the string. For instance, `b = 'banana'`. If you do `b = bytearray(b)`, then you have access to converting individual characters with `ord` like so: `b[0] = ord('B')`. This will produce `Banana`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stringInput="Banana"
listString=list(stringInput)
```

That's it. Easy peasy!