# How can I create an array from a .txt file?

Tags: python

I have a txt file of only a continuous string of characters MNHY...

I want to have the output of ['M','N','H','Y'...]

I have attempted this code below and various forms of it, but I can only convert the txt file as one continuous list.

```
def text_check(filename):
    my_file = open(filename,"r")
    print(my_file.read().splitlines())
text_check("demo_text.txt")
```

How can I convert the .txt file to this ['M','N','H','Y'...] format?

Comment: You know how to read lines from a file (though maybe you want to store the lines read in a variable before printing them..), now look up how to iterate over the items in a string (or how to convert it to a `list` of characters)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break string into list of characters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833392/break-string-into-list-of-characters-in-python)

Comment: okay thanks, i'll try to focus on looking this up! I feel like I am just getting easily lost due to my inexperience.

Comment: No worries , learning how (and where) to look things up is the frst step in learning how to code :) It takes a while, but it gets better very quickly! Normally, for very basic questions such as this one, there's always an answer already, the trick is learning the right search terms ;)

Comment: @MikeScotty I wish it were that easy! Listing it in a simple way just returns an empty list.

Comment: @GPhilo I think trying to improve my ability to search for solutions is also something i need to develop. It can be a bit of a minefeld even trying to search in the right way, any tips on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Simply use `list()` method.

The `list()` method in python will convert a continous string into seperate character.

In other words, the codes that work for you are:

```py
def text_check(filename):
    my_file = open(filename,"r")
    li_chars = list(my_file.read().splitlines()[0])
    print(li_chars)
    my_file.close()
text_check("demo_text.txt")
```

> 1. The `list()` method will do the spliting when it accepts a **string**, so I add `[0]` to `splitlines()`.
> 2. I add `my_file.close()` at the end of `text_check()`.

---

#### Improvements

```py
def text_check(filename):
    with open(filename,"r") as f:
        li_chars = list(f.read().splitlines()[0])
        print(li_chars)
text_check("demo_text.txt")
```

> The `with` statement provides a way for ensuring that a clean-up is always used.

Comment: Thanks, this returned the array with individual characters from the .txt file that i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file contains

```
MNYH…
```

you can use:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    out = list(f.read().strip())
print(out)
```

output: `['M', 'N', 'H', 'Y', '…']`

##### multi-line files

```
MNHY
ABCD
```

```
with open(filename) as f:
    out = [c for l in f for c in l.strip()]
```

output: `['M', 'N', 'H', 'Y', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

Comment: This returned a TypeError: Not Iterable on the object. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @nosebig which python version so you have? Are you sure the file only has a single line?

Comment: 3.7  It's multiple lines on the file, sorry if this wasn't clear from the .... continuation

Comment: @nosebig it should still work, but include the newline characters in the output. Can you check again? I updated the answer to handle the multi-line case